# display multiple django messages in one page?

Tags: django, forms, message

I have a template in which user can change his details like name, email and password. I am getting wrong messages after updating info ( if I change the password then I got message "Invalid" that is part of edit_profile) though I used extra_tags for message to identify two different messages,

But still having issue. I tried searching a lot, and found some relevant questions but was not helpful.

**views.py**

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Update successful!", extra_tags='edit_profile')
                return redirect("accounts:edit_profile")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Invalid", extra_tags='edit_profile')
                return redirect("accounts:edit_profile")

        else:
            form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            return render(request, "accounts/edit_profile.html", {'form': form})
    else:
        redirect('accounts:signin')


def change_password(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(data=request.POST, user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Update successful!", extra_tags='change_password')

            update_session_auth_hash(request, form.user)
            return redirect("accounts:change_password")
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Password Error", extra_tags='change_password')
            return redirect("accounts:change_password")

    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        return render(request, "accounts/edit_profile.html", {'form': form})
```

**template**

```
            <h2 class="font-weight-bolder">Account Details</h2>

            <!-- edit_profile form -->

            <form action="{% url 'accounts:edit_profile' %}" method="post" class="row g-3 needs-validation"
                  novalidate>

                {% csrf_token %}

                <!-- 1 Username  -->

                <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-4 ">
                    <label for="username" class="form-label">Username</label><br>
                    <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username"
                           value="{{ form.username.value }}" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide name.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- 2 Email  -->

                <div class="offset-md-1 col-md-4">
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                           value="{{ form.email.value }}" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide a valid email.
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% for message in messages %}

                    {% if 'edit_profile' in message.tags %}

                        <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-6 pt-2">
                            <h4 class="text-success font-weight-bolder">{{ message }}</h4>
                        </div>

                    {% endif %}

                {% endfor %}

                <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-4 pt-2 pb-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">
                </div>              
            </form>

            <!-- Password section -->

            <div class="offset-md-2 pt-3 pb-2">
                <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Password</h4>
            </div>

            <form action="{% url 'accounts:change_password' %}" method="post" class="row g-3 needs-validation"
                  novalidate>

                {% csrf_token %}

                <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-3">
                    <label for="old_password" class="form-label">Current password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="old_password" value="" class="form-control" id="old_password" required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide a valid password.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="new_password1" class="form-label">New password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="new_password1" value="" class="form-control" id="new_password1"
                           required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide a valid password.
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <label for="new_password2" class="form-label">Confirm password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="new_password2" value="" class="form-control" id="new_password2"
                           required>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please provide a valid password.
                    </div>
                </div>

                {% for message in messages %}

                    {% if "change_password" in message %}

                        <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-6 pt-2">
                            <h4 class="text-success font-weight-bolder">{{ message }}</h4>
                        </div>

                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}

                <div class="offset-md-2 col-md-4 pt-2">
                    <input type="submit" value="Change Password" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-lg">
                </div>
            </form>
```

Comment: You are using the same template for two different APIs. My best guess for the problem, is when you submit your password form, it reloads the whole page to render the response, and because of that your edit profile page also rendered and might give you the error. Actually you should not use the same template for 2 different APIs. Also as you are not able to update profile and password at the same time so why keeping both forms in same template. Divide them and your issue will be resolved.

Comment: Also `{% if "change_password" in message %}` should be `{% if "change_password" in message.tags %}`

Comment: @VineetYadav I wanna display user details on one page so that I am using same template, Is there any other way to solve this issue?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I also checked this one but still same issue

Comment: @MTayyab Password is something we do not usually consider in user's details. We do not show password to user under their profile, so we can show it on differnt page. But still if you want to provide it on same page, you can use the same form for details and password. Also use a single API to update them.

Comment: @VineetYadav I am not talking to show password to user, means I just want that user can change his password if he already know his current password, and I am sorry If I am unable to explain my question

Comment: @MTayyab What are the urls for the two views? Please [edit] and add them to your question.

Comment: @VineetYadav Thanks by using same form for details and password it works without any error.

Comment: @MTayyab as a hint I believe your problem was that both the views had the same urlpattern, causing only the first view to be used.

Comment: @MTayyab rendering the same template in different views is fine, I believe in your urls.py you had the same pattern for both views, i.e. `path('some_pattern', ....)` with `some_pattern` being the same in both / similar enough that first one catches both urls.